# Unable to get Code Coverage Report using jmockit coverage jar

Tags: java, code-coverage, jmockit

I have been using jmockit coverage while testing locally available jars in eclipse. But when I am trying to put the jmockit coverage jar on remote node with tomcat running, where I am deploying many of the jars. I am unable to generate coverage report for the same.

Emma works fine for remote coverage but wanted to use jmockit coverage for remote as well, because it is a bit more easier approach.

Comment: What is task you are running to get coverage ?

Comment: I am adding both the required jars in the classpath i.e. jmockit.jar and jmockit-coverage.jar. In case of local thing, i was getting the coverage report in eclipse without writing any specific task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<target name="Jmockit" >
        <junit fork="yes" forkmode="once" >
            <classpath refid="class.path" />
            <sysproperty key="jmockit-coverage-output" value="html" />
            <jvmarg value="-javaagent:../jmockit.jar"/> // path of Jmockit jar
            <formatter type="brief" usefile="false"/>
            <batchtest >
                <fileset dir ="${testdir}" includes="**/*.class" />
            </batchtest>
        </junit>
    </target>
```

Do something this .

Give the path of ${testdir}, your classpath reference and path of Jmockit.jar in this task..